# javascript check if img src is valid?

Tags: javascript, image, src

I have something like:

```
document.getElementById('MyPicture').src = 'attempted.png';
```

If the client cannot get that resource, I would like to replace it with:

```
document.getElementById('MyPicture').src = 'error.png'
```

I know I can put onError=function() in the image tag, but how can I pass the Id to onError, so that I can have one onError function that can change the src of any bad pics?

Answer (score 26):

Yes, you can use the `onerror` event, on image elements is really [widely supported](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/error.html), for example:

```
var image = document.getElementById('MyPicture');
image.onerror = function () {
  alert('error loading ' + this.src);
  this.src = 'error.png'; // place your error.png image instead
};

image.src = 'non-existing.jpg';
```

Check an example [here](http://jsbin.com/agonu3/2/).
​

Answer (score 5):

Put this in the image tag:

```
onError="image_error(this.id)"
```

which will pass the id of the image to image_error function.... duh

Answer (score 1):

Adding the onError attribute is indeed the correct way to handle it. In your case, you'd add something like:

```
var myPicture = document.getElementById('MyPicture');
myPicture.onError = errorHandler();

function errorHandler(msg,file_loc,line_num) {
  myPicture.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo1w.png';
}
```